# OnRowCommand from a GridView within User Control within a row of a GridView not firing

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, user-controls

I'm working on an ASP.Net Web forms web site, and I face the following situation.

I have a GridView, wich contains in some row a User Control, which contains a GridView. This last GridView had a OnRowCommand method and some buttons are supposed to fire this method. However, the OnRowCommand method is not fired...

Any idea or clue about this problem ? Maybe this GridViewception is not possible...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I guess you are databinding the outer or inner grid on every postback. Is viewstate enabled? Can you show relevant code(both, aspx and codebehind). Is anything added dynamically or everything added declaratively?

Comment: I will check about the ViewState. But do you mean enabled at the page level or control level ?

Comment: I'll think about it for the code but I think it will not be clear... Too much code...

Comment: You gave me a hint with the last thing. Indeed, the user control is added dynamically ! Maybe I need to declarate myself a listener or something like that.

Comment: why do you add it dynamically? If it's a grid you just need to put it in the `ItemTemplate`. If you don't want that it's visible by default, make it `Visible=False` and later `Visible=True`.

Comment: Actually, I want to add it "one in two" rows. A click on a row N show the row N+1 containing the UserControl.